# Prevent linux terminal from opening true path

Tags: linux, terminal

I'm working in a managed linux environment where I don't have root privileges. The OS is CentOS 6.9 and the terminal is GNOME terminal 2.31.3 (with bash).

This is the behavior I'm trying to fix:

Let's say I'm working in directory `/home/myname/x`. This is actually a symlink to some mangled, hidden path, like `/.hidden/123/argle/myname/x`. (I did not set it up this way, the root did)

I hit `ctrl+shift+t` (i.e. new tab) within the terminal.

In the new tab, my $PWD is now `/.hidden/123/argle/myname/x` rather than `/home/myname/x`.

I would like to prevent this from happening unless I explicitly go to this mangled directory. I would like to see `/home/myname/x` as my `$PWD` and in my prompt. (this has implications for debuggers etc)

Is there an environment variable I can set that would prevent this? Or any other measure that a non-root user can implement?

Comment: what happens to `$PWD` if you `cd ~/` ?

Comment: @drudge it shows up as `/home/myname`

Comment: This is the behavior of GNOME Terminal beginning with version 3.8 if I recall correctly. Mind you, you're using an 8 year old version. The best you can do there is some workaround in .bashrc that does a search-replace on the working directory and cd's there.